# Query is not returning expected results when using CASE statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

```
SELECT
    b.Part,
    b.PartCreated,
    b.LastSalesDate,
    CASE WHEN b.LastSalesDate < (getdate()-365) OR b.LastSalesDate IS NULL AND b.PartCreated <= '2013-12-31' THEN 'C'
         WHEN b.LastSalesDate < (getdate()-365) OR b.LastSalesDate IS NULL AND b.PartCreated >= '2014-01-01' THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'D'
    END AS PartType
```

I am getting incorrect results when running this query.  Some PartType values are coming out to be 'C' when it should be 'N'.  For example, Part 123456 has a PartCreated value of 02-17-2014 and a LastSalesDate value of 08-01-2014 and the PartType value should be 'N', but the query is returning 'C'.  How can I fix the query?

Comment: CASE EXPRESSION! (Not case statement...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` has higher priority than `OR` so the evaluation of the case expression might not be what you expect.

Your condition is evaluated as `a or (b and c)` but you want `(a or b) and c`

You can alter the evaluation by adding parentheses:

```
CASE WHEN (b.LastSalesDate < (getdate()-365) OR b.LastSalesDate IS NULL) AND b.PartCreated <= '2013-12-31' THEN 'C'
     WHEN (b.LastSalesDate < (getdate()-365) OR b.LastSalesDate IS NULL) AND b.PartCreated >= '2014-01-01' THEN 'N'
ELSE 'D'
END AS PartType
```